# When defined inside useEffect, the variable to highlight a div is not set properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code to identify from the URL if there is an item (i.e., `selectedActionCommentId`) to highlight. In such case, a message is displayed (using `toast`).

```
if (props.match.params.actionOrNote === "learningaction") {
    selectedActionId = parseInt(props.match.params.itemId);

    if (props.match.params.commentId !== null) {
        selectedActionCommentId = parseInt(props.match.params.commentId);

        toast.success("Some message.......", {
            position: toast.POSITION.TOP_CENTER
        });
    } 
}
```

When this code is put outside the `useEffect`, it works fine and inside `return` the matching div with `selectedActionCommentId` is highlighted properly. However, it is rendered so many times and the message is displayed multiple times.

If I put this inside the `useEffect`, then the message is displayed only once (which is perfect) but the div is not highlighted since not the proper `selectedActionId` is passed down (and I do not know why).

Any ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: To resolve this use `useState` and then it will render the changes when selectedActionCommentId state is changed.

Comment: Did you add `prop.match.params` to `useEffect` dependencies ?

Comment: sounds like he/she is probably trying to use selectActionCommentId in one of his child components as a prop to control highlighting.  And it's not accessible, because it's inside the useEffect function closure

Comment: @George yes, using state solved it. I wonder why a variable would not work ?

Comment: that's react. setting a variable doesn't let react know that it should re-render, so it has to be done explicitly by setting state. imagine if it re-rendered every time you set a variable in the function. actually, it will only re-render if you specify that state variable in the useEffect deps.